# How to add grub entry for encrypted partition

Tags: grub2, luks

I have luks2 encrypted partition on `/dev/sda6` under one `/` partition (installed leap already)

Later I have installed debian and ran os-prober after opening `sda6` with luksOpen and mounted it.

But os-prober did not detect it

What changes I need to make in `/etc/default/grub` and `grub.cfg` to boot into encrypted partitions?

Comment: Are both installs in UEFI boot mode? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
 Boot-Repair's default fix is to make first install as default. If you do not want that you must use its advanced mode. You do have to mount & decrypt both installs for Boot-Repair report to be complete.